# fatal error: xmlsec/xmlsec.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, package, xmlseclibs

I have a makefile as follows:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1
AuthClient : src/aadhaar.c src/uid_auth.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) src/aadhaar.c src/uid_auth.c -o $@
```

This is throwing a compilation error `xmlsec/xmlsec.h: No such file or directory`

I have downloaded the xmlsec1 and libxmlsec1 packages, but still the error continues. As expected, there is still no xmlsec directory under `/usr/include/` folder. Can someone help me out what would be the relevant package that I am missing?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `-dev` package (probably `libxmlsec1-dev`) installed?

Comment: Thanks @vlp, btw anyway if you know **"xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad"** is in which library? The same Makefile is now giving an error - undefined reference to 'xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad' . I have installed the dev package for _libltdl_ and _libxslt_ and I am stuck on it from long. Is it that these packages are not properly linked in the Makefile?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev
```